# why I need to tap twice on the cell in UITableView for Alert to show up

Tags: swift, tableview, uialertcontroller

I have a simple tableView and the idea is that when user tap on on a cell  alert pops up - but for some reason I have to tap twice for alert to show up why is that?
my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
        IndexPath) {

        let employee = employees[indexPath.row]

        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Stämpelklocka", 
            message: employee.firstName + " " + employee.lastName, 
            preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Avbryt", style: 
            .destructive) { (action) in

        }
        let accept = UIAlertAction(title: "Stämpla Ut?", style: 
            UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
        }

        alertView.addAction(cancel)
        alertView.addAction(accept)
        present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code which might require you to tap twice for the alert to appear. Have you tried debugging to see where it gets stuck?

Comment: You probably have some kind of tap recognisor on the view which has to fail before passing events backwards to the tableview

Comment: Would you mind sharing the whole class? I can not see how @Sh_Khan's answer should be the solution as your code isn't wrong. Did you implement `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` too?

Comment: no I did not sir...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to deselect it here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
    IndexPath) {


    let employee = employees[indexPath.row]

    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Stämpelklocka", 
        message: employee.firstName + " " + employee.lastName, 
        preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Avbryt", style: 
        .destructive) { (action) in

    }
    let accept = UIAlertAction(title: "Stämpla Ut?", style: 
        UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
    }

    alertView.addAction(cancel)
    alertView.addAction(accept)
    present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

     // deselect 
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

 }
```

Comment: that is correct:) (will accpet your answer in 3 min ) - could U pls explain the logic behind it so that I can understand the reason...?:)

Comment: I'd love to hear an explanation to this too as I can not see anything wrong with **not** deselecting the row manually.